# JavaScript: Parse and Paste Text from Clipboard to PDF document

Tags: javascript, parsing, pdf, clipboard

I've got an PDF document with 2 editable text fields: "surname" and "email".

Now the Email ALWAYS consists of this format: Name.Surname@email.com . So I can simply copy the email and I already have got the data I need in the memory/clipboard.

Now I need JavaScript to do 2 things:

1) Copy the email into the "email" field on Open-Document event.

2) Parse the Name.Surname@email.com and only copy the Surname into the "surname" text field

Before the PDF document is opened, the Name.Surname@mail.com already has been copied to the memory. Now when I open the PDF document, I want both things 1) 2) done.

How do I go about this please?

Answer (score 0):

Create `onchange` handler and parse input data by regexp. Then manually update fields.

Comment: Not exactly what I'm looking for. Sorry for my bad description. Before the PDF document is opened, the Name.Surname@mail.com already has been copied to the memory. Now when I open the PDF document, I want both things 1) 2) done.

Comment: What program you are using to open PDF? Even if you are using browser (using some plugin) js doesn't have an access to another tab. And js don't have an access to clipboard.

Comment: You want javascript pasting some data from clipboard to another application? That's totally impossible.